# Sub-aggregations on group by sets?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a data summary table that looks like this:

```
create table event_summary (
  created_at timestamp,
  ad_id integer,
  views integer,
  unique_views integer,
  clicks integer,
  unique_clicks integer,
  price integer
);
create index on event_summary using BRIN (created_at);
```

I'm trying to express myself only in SQL, but had a hard time understanding how to aggregate on sets within the group by. I have the following query:

```
select
  sum(views),
  sum(unique_views),
  sum(clicks),
  sum(unique_clicks),
  price
from event_summary
group by ad_id, price
order by views desc
```

The query works great. Then, in my application code, I can calculate the cost per mile of every `ad_id` since the `price` has been separated. So I take the `views` value and multiply by `price`. Then I sum all values and I have a final cost per mile for every `ad_id`.

But I'm curious about group by grouping sets, or even roll ups. Would it be possible, or even recommended, to do this calculation on SQL?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want to achieve. You mention "cost per milie", "grouping sets", "roll ups". It's not clear what you mean....

Comment: The `grouping sets`, `cube` and `rollup` are [`group by` clauses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) in PostgreSQL. If that's the only question then yes, it's both possible and recommended to get the whole result you're after, in one go, without splitting the query logic between the db and the app, if you can help it.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. In my code, I take the sum(views) and do a multiplication by the value of price, for each result of the group by. I was wondering if it was possible to do that within the grouping set, or the cube.

Comment: Something like GROUP BY ad_id, SUM(views) * price

Comment: Can you add an `insert` statement with some sample data and an example result that you'd like the query to deliver based on that sample?

Comment: Here's a full example: https://dbfiddle.uk/LVLpBTMY

Comment: (113231×1760) + (131101×1800) = cost per mile for ID 2

Comment: I think what I'm basically asking is for the possibility of arithmetic in sub-aggregation groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can actually get away with a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) and a [subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IFYDmcqj)

```sql
select *,
       sum(views_sum*price)over(partition by ad_id) as cost_per_mile
from(select ad_id,
            sum(views)         as views_sum,
            sum(unique_views)  as unique_views_sum,
            sum(clicks)        as clicks_sum,
            sum(unique_clicks) as unique_clicks_sum,
            price
     from event_summary
     group by ad_id, price 
) AS subquery;
```

| ad_id | views_sum | unique_views_sum | clicks_sum | unique_clicks_sum | price | cost_per_mile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 115109 | 36892 | 12166 | 8555 | 1760 | 364890640 |
| 1 | 90166 | 37656 | 13606 | 8683 | 1800 | 364890640 |
| 2 | 112170 | 36716 | 13889 | 6330 | 1760 | 409178400 |
| 2 | 117644 | 40753 | 11531 | 6793 | 1800 | 409178400 |
| 3 | 103802 | 35926 | 13843 | 7130 | 1800 | 381687920 |
| 3 | 110707 | 43738 | 12581 | 6989 | 1760 | 381687920 |

---

If the only reason you grouped by `price` was to calculate things off-database, you can get rid of that, then go ahead and use the arithmetics within the aggregate function: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/awTETR2n)

```sql
select  ad_id,
        sum(views)         as views_sum,
        sum(unique_views)  as unique_views_sum,
        sum(clicks)        as clicks_sum,
        sum(unique_clicks) as unique_clicks_sum,
        sum(views*price)   as cost_per_mile
from event_summary
group by ad_id
order by ad_id;
```

| ad_id | views_sum | unique_views_sum | clicks_sum | unique_clicks_sum | cost_per_mile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 205275 | 74548 | 25772 | 17238 | 364890640 |
| 2 | 229814 | 77469 | 25420 | 13123 | 409178400 |
| 3 | 214509 | 79664 | 26424 | 14119 | 381687920 |

[Here's the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) discussing full aggregate function call syntax - note it says *expression* not *column*, which means that there's quite a lot of flexibility that includes the arithmetics above. At the top of the page you can see 15 other types of expressions, the list of which isn't exhaustive.

Comment: The values in my example are different from [your db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LVLpBTMY) because you didn't save the seed, so the `random()` calls in my run resulted in different values from yours. Use [`select setseed(0.1);`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE) before calling `random()` to stabilise the seed between runs.

Comment: Never knew about the setseed() or Window Functions. Thank you!